# refresh datatable data in lwc while using imperative method

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lwc-wire-adapter, datatable, imperativeapex

I have used the Braintree payment gateway to payments on 'Order' object. For this I have created the datatable to fetch the 'TotalAmount' field from the particular record and I'm calling it Imperatively (in connectedCallback method). After that I'm taking the valuf of TotalAmount from the datatable and passing it to the method (processPayment) whcih is my REST class.

But the problem is that whenever I add products in the order, I need to refresh the page for the latest value of TotalAmount. I tried using the rendredCallback method but it is throwing the error.

Can someone pls help me so that I can pass the updated value in the processPayment method without refreshing the page?

Comment: Auto refresh based on what criteria? What have you tried so far? Where did you got stuck? Can you also add minimal required code by editing your question?

Comment: Hi @Sanket, i have added the code and pls suggest what can be done

Comment: If your template uses properties populated by your code using the return values from the imperative call, the UI will auto-refresh. If you have a complex structure or array for the data you may need to mark the property holding this data as `@track`ed.

Comment: Hi Phil, I have modified the question, can you please check.

Comment: You assign `latestValue = newOrderAmt[0];` and I suspect this should be `this.latestValue = newOrderAmt[0];`. The total amount calculation just before that looks wrong, BTW.

Comment: The **latestValue** is fetching the value, there is no issue. The problem is that it should auto refresh and update in the datatable

Comment: I don't see any code. Did someone remove it?